# Why tapping the bat on the pitch is not considered illegal?

Tags: cricket

Why does tapping the bat on the pitch (including the danger zone) not considered as illegal but a bowler running over the danger zone is given a warning?

I assume that even if a batsman is "gardening" the pitch   around the bowler's foot marks (on a spinning track), it will not be considered as illegal.

Answer (score -2):

Tapping the pitch using bat is common practice, as it has been done for so long. I guess in olden days the game was tilted towards the bowlers so much. No helmet or good protection from personal harm. All batsmen could do was tap the pitch, which does not make much of a difference anyways.